# Jetpack wordpress JSON API is not working

Tags: php, json, wordpress, jetpack

I have installed `Jetpack` Plugin and using `JSON` data in my iOS App.

Now Jetpack JSON Plugin is not working.

I use my website like this.

```
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.myWebsite.com/posts/
```

I have already connected with `wordpress` account.
Now Jetpack is showing error like this.

```
{"error":"jetpack_error","message":"The Jetpack site is inaccessible or returned an error: transport error - HTTP status code was not 200 [-32300]"}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you typed the site correct and it's actually open? Because if I use my blog, it works.

Comment: yes , i am sure it's correct. My others website is working fine.

Comment: Have you disabled access to xmlrpc.php perhaps?

Comment: no. i didn't do anything. First it's fine and working perfect with iOS  App about 1 month. Now it's happening.

Comment: when i test xmlrpc.php with my website link. It's showing "XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only."

Comment: Did you recently update the plugin? You might also want to check out the Jetpack/Wordpress forums, you might not be the only one with this problem.

Comment: Even I am getting the same problem, did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iPage Hosting for my website. Problem solved when i report it to hosting service and they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I Am using TNP HOST web hosting and it worked for me .

Asked from support team and dont know exactly what they did but it worked .